# No icon in MATE applications menu

Tags: mate-desktop, icons

Today I noticed I have no icons in categories of the MATE application menu, that is:

[image]

And they don't appear in the menu editor, either:
[image]

Running openSUSE Tumbleweed, MATE 1.24.0 and my system is up to date. It happens with any icon theme or GTK theme I try.

What should I check?